# 404 with keycloak step1.html

Tags: keycloak

I was able to get the keycloak SPA quickstart [demo](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/23.0.3/js/spa) working.  But when I try to do an example on my own keycloak.js keeps using the port of the app, not  the keycloak port.  In other words keycloak.js is trying to reach keycloak on port 8080 instead of port 8180 as I configured.

The only differences I see are

- My app entry url has a node the "shell" node.
- I used the javascript config instead of keycloak.json
- Different realm

All of those are because I'm testing keycloak on a Micro Front End solution.  The first two don't seem like items that should cause any differences.  Is there a realm setting that could change this?

Can you offer any suggestions?  I'm using keycloak 23.03.  Both apps are using the same keycloak instance.

**quickstart**

- app entry url - http://localhost:8080
- call to step1.html - http://localhost:8180/realms/quickstart/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html

> ```
> {
>   "realm": "quickstart",
>   "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180",
>   "ssl-required": "external",
>   "resource": "spa",
>   "public-client": true
> }
> ```

**My Example**

- app entry url - http://localhost:8080/shell
- call to step1.html - http://localhost:8080/realms/lifeinsurace/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html

> ```
> const keycloak = new Keycloak({
>           "realm": "lifeinsurace",
>       "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180",
>       "ssl-required": "external",
>           "resource": "lifeinsurace-appshell",
>           "public-client": true,
>       "clientId":"lifeinsurace-appshell"
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `realm/users` data and add `/shell` endpoint too.

Step 1: Keycloak launching

Step 2: Import realm/users

Step 3: Modify `index.html`

Step 4: Launching `express` server

Step 5: login user

##### Step 1: Keycloak launching

Version 23.0.3
Port 8180

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.3
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8180:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

Run it

```
docker compose up
```

##### Step 2: Import realm/users

Save as 'realm-shell-import.json'

```json
{
  "realm": "lifeinsurace",
  "enabled": true,
  "clients": [
    {
      "clientId": "lifeinsurace-appshell",
      "enabled": true,
      "publicClient": true,
      "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true,
      "redirectUris": [ "http://localhost:8080/shell/*" ]
    }
  ],
  "users" : [
    {
      "username" : "alice",
      "enabled": true,
      "email" : "alice@keycloak.org",
      "firstName": "Alice",
      "lastName": "Liddel",
      "credentials" : [
        { "type" : "password",
          "value" : "alice" }
      ],
      "realmRoles": [ "user", "offline_access"  ],
      "clientRoles": {
        "account": [ "manage-account" ]
      }
    },
    {
      "username" : "admin",
      "enabled": true,
      "email" : "test@admin.org",
      "firstName": "Admin",
      "lastName": "Test",
      "credentials" : [
        { "type" : "password",
          "value" : "admin" }
      ],
      "realmRoles": [ "user","admin" ],
      "clientRoles": {
        "realm-management": [ "realm-admin" ],
        "account": [ "manage-account" ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "roles" : {
    "realm" : [
      {
        "name": "user",
        "description": "User privileges"
      },
      {
        "name": "admin",
        "description": "Administrator privileges"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

After Import
[image]

[image]

##### Step 3: Modify `index.html`

File location
[image]

It will include this code

```html
      const keycloak = new Keycloak({
        "realm": "lifeinsurace",
        "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180",
        "ssl-required": "external",
        "resource": "lifeinsurace-appshell",
        "public-client": true,
        "clientId":"lifeinsurace-appshell"
      });
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Keycloak Single-Page Application Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="user" style="display: none;">
      <button id="logout" type="button">Logout</button>
      <button id="showMyAccount" type="button">My Account</button>
      <button id="showIdToken" type="button">Show ID Token</button>
      <button id="showAccessToken" type="button">Show Access Token</button>
      <button id="refreshToken" type="button">Refresh</button>
      <hr>
      <h2 id="name"></h2>
      <pre id="output"></pre>
    </div>
    <script src="KC_URL/js/keycloak.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
      const outputElement = document.getElementById("output");
      const nameElement = document.getElementById("name");
      const userElement = document.getElementById("user");

      function output(content) {
        if (typeof content === "object") {
          content = JSON.stringify(content, null, 2);
        }

        outputElement.textContent = content;
      }

      function showProfile() {
        const name =
          keycloak.idTokenParsed.name ||
          keycloak.idTokenParsed.preferred_username;

        nameElement.textContent = `Hello ${name}`;
        userElement.style.display = "block";
      }

      document.getElementById("logout").addEventListener("click", () => {
        keycloak.logout();
      });

      document.getElementById("showIdToken").addEventListener("click", () => {
        output(keycloak.idTokenParsed);
      });

      document
        .getElementById("showAccessToken")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
          output(keycloak.tokenParsed);
        });

      document
        .getElementById("refreshToken")
        .addEventListener("click", async () => {
          await keycloak.updateToken(-1);
          output(keycloak.idTokenParsed);
          showProfile();
        });

      document
        .getElementById("showMyAccount")
        .addEventListener("click", async () => {
          await keycloak.accountManagement()
        });

      const keycloak = new Keycloak({
        "realm": "lifeinsurace",
        "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180",
        "ssl-required": "external",
        "resource": "lifeinsurace-appshell",
        "public-client": true,
        "clientId":"lifeinsurace-appshell"
      });
      await keycloak.init({ onLoad: "login-required" });
      showProfile();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

##### Step 4: launching `express` server

Save as 'app.js'

```js
import express from 'express';
import stringReplace from 'string-replace-middleware';

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(stringReplace({
  KC_URL: process.env.KC_URL || "http://localhost:8180"
}));

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.use('/shell', express.static('shell'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}.`);
});
```

Install dependencies

```
npm install
```

With the same `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "spa",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "npm run create-realm && npx playwright test --project=chromium && npm run delete-realm",
    "create-realm": "node scripts/create-realm.js",
    "delete-realm": "node scripts/delete-realm.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@keycloak/keycloak-admin-client": "23.0.6",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "string-replace-middleware": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.33.0"
  }
}
```

Run it

```
npm start
```

##### Step 5: login user

Open Browser

```
http://localhost:8080/shell/
```

[image]

```
username: admin
password: admin
```

Result
[image]

[image]